# Knowing when a JFrame is fully drawn

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a program that creates a `JFrame` and makes it visible. Is there anyway to know when the `JFrame` is fully drawn and visible? Right now a hacky "wait and pray" method is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [add](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener(java.awt.event.WindowListener)) a [`WindowListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to the `JFrame`; then when [`windowOpened`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)) is fired, the window should be visible.

Comment: Changed to a listener approach (for reference, the original answer suggested checking isShowing()).

Comment: Ok I just realised that I am asking the wrong question. I'm creating a JFrame in a thread, then I want that thread to wait for the Jframe to appear. But since that frame doesn't exist yet I have no way to grab a reference to it. (Of course I'm using reflection to create the frame, just to complicate things). 
So I think that the real question is "How can yield and specifically wait for the Swing thread to execute". 
Should I make a new question?

Answer (score 1):

to answer the "How can yield and specifically wait for the Swing thread to execute" question:

you can use a [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

**edit** 
reading your comment once more i see a potentially problematic statement:

> I'm creating a JFrame in a thread, then I want that thread to wait for the JFrame to appear.

are you calling your `frame.setVisible(true)` in this thread as well?  If so, you should probably be reminded that Swing painting should all be handled on the AWT EventQueue.  This is where the `SwingWorker` comes in.

However, what you may need for the 'yield and wait' is a wait/notify operation.  In your calling thread you can wait on a shared Object:

```
synchronized (frameShowingLock) {
     frameShowingLock.wait()'
}
```

then in your SwingWorker, or wherever you call frame.setVisible(true) you can finish the process by using the `notifyAll()` method to wake up your waiting thread:

```
 synchronized (frameShowingLock) {
     frameShowingLock.notifyAll()'
}
```

Comment: how specifically? I'm not exactly sure how it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try overriding  `Component.addNotify()` which I believe is called when the component is drawn. Just make sure to call `super.addNotify()`.

```
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    // after displayed handling
}
```